# Ionic mobile app using Cassandra, what about local storage?

Tags: ionic-framework, cassandra, nosql

I am working on a project using Ionic for the mobile side, I have a web app as well linked to a Cassandra database.

I need data synchronization between the mobile device (local storage) and the server-hosted Cassandra database. I use the cassandra-driver to connect to the database but then I realize how problematic it is to convert the data to an other type of database (SQLite for example).

Should I rather use an other database than Cassandra to make the synchronization easier ? (I need a noSQL solution)

Answer (score 1):

Choice of the database depends on type of data you want to store. Cassandra is a column oriented database. It has great performance when you have to deal with large amount of data, but has many limitations related to the queries you need in order to pull data. For that reason, it might require additional efforts to develop something that you could easily do with some other database. So, the real question is do you really need Cassandra.

If you are using it only for mobile application, I don't think you will have so much data to exploit Cassandra benefits.

In your place, I would rather consider some other databases, such as MongoDB in case JSON is appropriate format for your data or Redis if you data is key/value pairs.

Comment: I choose Cassandra because I deal with a large amount of data, I have an account system and every user have a diary where various data can be recorded, and stored in such way that analysis of those data is possible. In a way similar to Facebook.
But even mongodb would be problematic for local storage on the phone wouldn't be?

Comment: If you want to use local storage, MongoDB would not work. I suggested it as remote DB as you indicated in your question. In case you want to look for local storage solution, you might consider PouchDB as local storage and CouchDB as remote DB instead. Both MongoDB and CouchDB are good choice for remote DB when you deal with large amount of data, and store documents in JSON format so it would be easy to synchronize with PouchDB. Cassandra is not the only database that works well with large amount of data, so you should consider other aspects before you choose your stack.